# Why “Stash pull request builder plugin” for Jenkins enabled emailing?

Tags: java, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, bitbucket-server

Each team member receives emails about each push to branches, from which pull requests are created.
But I can not see any email settings in this plugin:

```
- Stash pull request builder plugin
```

How to disable this stuff?